# parameter view in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to pass some variable in query and need to use result set in reporting tool like spotfire.

```
select prod_id,sum(sal)
from cal c
where qtr_num in (:q)
group by 1
having sum(sal)>0;
```

:q can be single value('Q1') or multiple values('Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4') as well.

I know we can use macro as parameter view. but we can not use result set returned by that macro in select part/reporting tool.

other option is to create view without filter and then use that view with parameter filter.

```
create view v 
as
(select prod_id,sum(sal)
from cal c
group by 1
having sum(sal)>0);

   select *
   from v
   where qtr_num in (:q);
```

but this approach may skip partition access(created on qtr_num) and inefficient way to query in my opinion. This query is just for demonstrate purpose. actual query is much more complex than this.

Is there any way to achieve this in teradata?

Comment: I was tinkering with a method using strtok_split_to_table that probably would have worked, however it caused a crashdump on my system... so I would advise against that.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, I was tinkering with `strtok_split_to_table` as a solution to split a delimited list of values into records, and then use that source to filter a query. I got a crash dump for my efforts, but I figured I would share my thoughts here in case it helps lead to something less crash-prone. Perhaps whatever issue I hit is resolved in 15.10.

Filtering field `f1` in table `test` in a view using parameter `:q` which is a list of comma delimited values (this works fine until it's crammed into a view, so perhaps a macro would behave better:

```
CREATE VIEW test_view AS
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE test.f1 in 
    (
        SELECT d.token 
        FROM TABLE 
            (
                strtok_split_to_Table(1, :q, ',') 
                RETURNS (outkey integer, tokennum integer, token varchar(20) character set unicode ) 
            ) d
    );
```